# How to delete row with different data types?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with a `KEY` column like this

```
KEY    

1FTqzqJƒQHScTJYWhEVdQF8REwFgyJI3zshƒATrKPtE=
1115072
1115033
1115103
1115042
1115070
H5AM1mp1AuYƒYtzcHa7gXr4ikIwFsaaTotyiMX88j¥I=
```

I want to delete all rows that is `INT`

My expected result is this:

```
KEY    

1FTqzqJƒQHScTJYWhEVdQF8REwFgyJI3zshƒATrKPtE=
H5AM1mp1AuYƒYtzcHa7gXr4ikIwFsaaTotyiMX88j¥I=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a regex to filter only numeric values

```
delete from mytable
where key ~ '^\d+$'
```